# When using WebP and Varnish, should WebP be added to line 82 of the VCL file?

Tags: magento2, varnish

varnish.vcl :

```
 ...
    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org trac/wikiFAQCompression
            if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
Line 82 ---- >  if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
                    # No point in compressing these
                    unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
                } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
                    set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
                } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
                    set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
                } else {
                    # unknown algorithm
                    unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
                }
        }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes.

But the long answer is: this snippet is obsolete since Varnish 4.x, because it already does `Accept-Encoding` normalization internally.

So removing it is best, unless you're using old Varnish like v3.

From the [docs](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/users-guide/compression.html?highlight=accept%20encoding):

> Unless returning from vcl_recv with pipe or pass, Varnish modifies req.http.Accept-Encoding: if the client supports gzip req.http.Accept-Encoding is set to "gzip", otherwise the header is removed.

I really don't know why everyone is so late on picking up that change.. :)